# Query using joins (many m:n relations)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I have to do the following query either with Rails' active record or sql (sqlite).

Let's start with the description of the model.

- User  1:n  Interest
- Interest  m:n  Category
- Interest  m:n  Location
- Event  m:n  Category
- Event  m:n  Location

m:n relationships are being made possible through a third table with the pattern interests_categories, events_categories, etc.

I've got users and those users have interests (Categories -> e.g. Sport, Music and locations he likes). Events get tagged with locations and categories.

Now I'd like to list all the users that might fit to a specific events. For example, if there's an event that takes place in NYC and has something todo in sports, I'd like to get a list of users that might be interested in this event based on the location and categories.

I'd like to do it in a single database access instead of multiple. 
How would that look like in ActiveRecord or sql? (The more efficient way would be prefered)
I'll probably have to join the Category/Location tables first, join the interests based on all the tables of the previously join and then select all the users based on the interests.
Unfortunately I have limited knowledge of joins sql. Or is there even a different approach available?

Comment: I don't think you have the data model right.  I think User is related to Location instead of Interest.

Comment: the table "interest" contains additional information. I just found out that it's possible to combine several queries. this is probably the way to go. Have to do some research now on that.

Comment: I should have said, I think User is related to Interest and Location, rather than Interest related to Location.

Comment: I don't see link between User and Event. Share your models structure.

Comment: there is no direct relation between a user and an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some thought I think this join will work.

```
class Events
  def get_users

User.joins(%"inner join interests on interests.user_id = users.id
             inner join categories_interests
               on categories_interests.interest_id = interests.id
             inner join categories on categories_interests.category_id = categories.id
             inner join interests_locations
               on interests_locations.interest_id = interests.id
             inner join locations on interests_locations.location_id = locations.id
             inner join categories_events on categories_events.category_id = categories.id
             inner join events_locations on events_locations.location_id = locations.id
             inner join events
               on categories_events.event_id = events.id
               and events_locations.event_id = events.id").where("events.id = :eid", :eid => id)

  end
end
```